# Join where records dont match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to do a join on two tables, I need EVERYTHING from table A, and just the stuff from table B where the 'REF' for each row, is not already in table A's results.

Key Facts:
Table B contains the complete amount of ID's/Names however all the other information is blank. Its basically just a table with all employee's name's and id's but its a complete list.
Table A contains a limited amount of results but all the other columns have data in them.

What I need is to use Table B as a complete reference rather than just see what exists in table A so basically:

> "Show me everything from table A, and add the extra people's details
>   found in table B where they dont already exist in table A to give me a complete result set"

```
select
ID,
Name,
StartDate,
EndDate,
State,
Status,
Comment,
IsComment
from
tableA


select
ID,
Name,
StartDate,
EndDate,
State,
Status,
Comment,
IsComment
from
tableB
```

Table A contents:

```
ID       Name     START_DATE       END_DATE      STATE    Status     Comment    Is_Comment
6760    chris       2012-09-03      2012-09-09   4       Applied                   0
6524     dave     2012-09-03        2012-09-09    4        Applied                 0
4268     james    2012-09-03        2012-09-09    4        Applied    Friday-Off   1
7851     rob      2012-09-03        2012-09-09    4       Applied                  0
```

Table B contents

```
    ID        Name     START_DATE       END_DATE      STATE    Status     Comment    Is_Comment
    6760    Chris   
    6524    dave    
    4268    james   
    7851    rob      
    4521    ryan
    5698   julie
    4596    rory
    1111     mary
    5621     owain
    9999     jacob
```

After the join what I want to see:

```
    ID       Name     START_DATE       END_DATE      STATE    Status     Comment    Is_Comment

    6760    chris       2012-09-03      2012-09-09   4       Applied                   0
    6524     dave     2012-09-03        2012-09-09    4        Applied                 0
    4268     james    2012-09-03        2012-09-09    4        Applied    Friday-Off   1
    7851     rob      2012-09-03        2012-09-09    4       Applied                  0   
   4521    ryan
   5698    julie
   4596    rory
  1111     mary
  5621     owain
  9999     jacob
```

Comment: I tried doing a left join on (sub query which gives Table B's results) On tableb.id <> tablea.id

Comment: It is a very easy LEFT join problem, you just have to change the select list, that get the info from the referenced table. Check my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Left join

```
SELECT [columnsListYouNeed]
FROM  TableB 
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for. He wants record's that DONT match from Table B, not records that do match as the LEFT JOIN will produce.

Comment: @general exception, not sure what you are implying, but B Left Join A is what the OP is looking for. I think the downvote is wrong.

Comment: @tranceporter Apologies. Misread the answer. p.s. I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select
tableB.ID,
tableB.Name,
tableA.StartDate,
tableA.EndDate,
tableA.State,
tableA.Status,
tableA.Comment,
tableA.IsComment
from
tableB
LEFT JOIN tableA on tableB.ID = tableA.ID
```

Because then every `ID` and `Name` will be listed **from tableB**, and every other column is listed from tableA. 
If there is no connection between the tables, then the other columns got the NULL from TableA - *because of LEFT JOIN* -, if there is a connection then you get the filled values from TableA also.

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14036/2) how this simple solution works.

Comment: I should probably add that these tables dont exist and are just two seperate queries and Name in table A is coming from a subquery already

Comment: Queries but selecting data from where?:) In your question there is a tableA and tableB.

Comment: Selecting data from the two tables, however there are a couple of case statements and a subquery to get me the Name

Comment: You can use your queries to get "TableA" and "TableB" just like changin the tableA and tableB in the script like: FROM (your query) AS tableA LEFT JOIN (your tableA query) AS tableA on tableB.ID = tableA.ID

Answer (score 1):

Please use this SQL:

```
declare @tableA table 
(
ID int,
Name nvarchar(250),
Age int
)

declare @tableB table 
(
ID int,
Name nvarchar(250),
Age int
)

Insert @tableA values (1,'a',10);
Insert @tableA values (2,'b',20);

Insert @tableB values (1,'a',null);
Insert @tableB values (2,'b',null);
Insert @tableB values (3,'c',null);
Insert @tableB values (4,'d',null);

select  tblResult.*,T1.Age from 
(
select ID,Name from @tableA
union
select ID,Name from @tableB) as tblResult 
left join @tableA as T1 on tblResult.ID =T1.ID
```